# How-to specialize template method in subclass(c++)?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, templates, template-specialization

I'm trying to specialize a template method of non-template class in its subclass:

// .h file

```
class MyWriter {
public:
    template<typename T>
    void test(const T & val) {
        std::cout << val << "\n";
    }
};
```

// .cpp file

```
class MyType {
public:
    MyType(int aa, double dd) : a(aa), d(dd) {}
    int a;
    double d;
};

class MyWriterExt : public MyWriter {
public:
    template<> void test(const MyType &val) {
        test(val.a);
        test(val.d);
    }
};

int main() {
    MyWriterExt w;
    w.test(10);
    w.test(9.999);
    w.test(MyType(15, 0.25));
 return 0;
}
```

But I receive an error:

```
Error 1 **error C2912**: explicit specialization; 
'void MyWriterExt::test(const MyType &)' is not a specialization of a function 
    template \testtemplate.cpp 30
```

How do I extend MyWriter class to support user defined classes?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Specialization should be done for the same class not for a subclass and also outside of the class body:

```
class MyWriter {
public:
    template<typename T>
    void test(const T & val) {
        std::cout << val << "\n";
    }
};

template<>
void MyWriter::test<MyType>(const MyType & val) {
    test(val.a);
    test(val.d);
}
```

You don't need a subclass to specialize the original member function template.

Also consider [overloading](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xlcpp8a.doc/language/ref/overl.htm) instead of specialization.

Answer (score 5):

### How to correct your compilation error?

```
Error 1 **error C2912**: explicit specialization; 
 'void MyWriterExt::test(const MyType &)' is not a specialization of
     a function template \testtemplate.cpp 30
```

If you want a "specialization" of the templated function in the derived class, the solution is to (in the derived class):

- overload the templated function with a normal function for your MyType parameter
- "import" the templated function into the current class (so it won't be hidden by the overload)

Which gives:

```
class MyWriterExt : public MyWriter {
public:
/*
    template<> void test(const MyType &val) {
        test(val.a);
        test(val.d);
    }
*/
    using MyWriter::test ;
    void test(const MyType &val) {
        test(val.a);
        test(val.d);
    }

};
```

### How to code correctly what you want to do?

> How do I extend MyWriter class to support user defined classes?

Now, if you are using MyWriter as an extensible output stream, I'm not sure inheritance is the solution. As already answered by [vitaut on his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176951/how-to-specialize-template-method-in-subclassc/4176967#4176967); you should specialize your templated function for (and outside) the base object.

### How to code *even more* correctly what you want to do?

> How do I extend MyWriter class to support user defined classes?

A better solution would be to follow the C++ stream's convention, that is, using non-friend, non-member functions. In your case, it would be something like:

```
class MyWriter {
public:
};

template<typename T>
MyWriter & operator << (MyWriter & writer, const T & val) {
    std::cout << val << "\n";
    return writer ;
}
```

Anyone could then "specialize" your output function without needing inheritance:

```
MyWriter & operator << (MyWriter & writer, const MyType & val) {
    writer << val.a << val.d ;
    return writer ;
}
```

Which could be written in your main as:

```
int main() {
    MyWriter w;
    w << 10 << 9.999 << MyType(15, 0.25);
 return 0;
}
```

Which is, IMHO, quite clearer than an accumulation of function calls (as long as you're not doing formatting, the C++ output streams are SO easy to use).

*(of course, I assume MyWriter will do more than a simple redirection to `std::cout`. If not, MyWriter is useless...)*